# How to access matching rule details in Camunda DMN in a Spring Boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, matching, camunda, rule-engine, dmn

My Spring Boot app connects to the Camunda BPMN & DMN. When a user clicks on Approve/Reject button in UI screen, a REST call triggers one BPMN workflow (in Camunda Spring Boot app) which internally triggers a DMN to find the output based on some business rules mapped in DMN input columns. We need to find the exact matching rules details like list of matching rules - input values, output values, matching rule ID, etc.

There are no inbuilt methods present in process engine and dmn engine and hence need to know if there is a way to manually configure such capabilities to the default process engine that comes as part of Spring Boot auto-configuration.

Camunda version:
7.13.0

Answer (score 0):

In a Spring Boot app, if we have these dependencies in pom.xml - camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter, camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp, camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest, a default Process Engine will be auto-configured during the startup of the Spring Boot app. But this Process Engine does not by default enable the Rule details. So we configure a custom Process Engine plugin which will be applied on top of the default Process Engine in order to get the matching rule details every time DMN is hit.

```
import org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.annotation.EnableProcessApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableProcessApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Customize Process Engine:

```
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEnginePlugin;
import org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.configuration.Ordering;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

@Configuration
public class CamundaConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordering.DEFAULT_ORDER + 1)
    public static ProcessEnginePlugin customProcessEnginePluginConfig() {
        return new CustomProcessEnginePlugin();
    }   
}
```

Our `CustomProcessEnginePlugin` will extend `AbstractCamundaConfiguration` and `override postInit()` method. This `postInit()` method adds a `DmnDecisionTableEvaluationListener`. This listner triggers an event everytime DMN is hit with matching rule and has `notify()` method with event details which contains all the DMN details like `dmnID` and matching rules detail.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.camunda.bpm.dmn.engine.delegate.DmnDecisionTableEvaluationEvent;
import org.camunda.bpm.dmn.engine.delegate.DmnDecisionTableEvaluationListener;
import org.camunda.bpm.dmn.engine.delegate.DmnEvaluatedDecisionRule;
import org.camunda.bpm.dmn.engine.delegate.DmnEvaluatedInput;
import org.camunda.bpm.dmn.engine.impl.DefaultDmnEngineConfiguration;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.variable.value.TypedValue;
import org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.configuration.Ordering;
import org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.configuration.impl.AbstractCamundaConfiguration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Component
@Order(Ordering.DEFAULT_ORDER + 1)
public class CustomProcessEnginePlugin extends AbstractCamundaConfiguration {
    @Override
    public void postInit(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl processEngineConfig) {
        DefaultDmnEngineConfiguration dmnEngineConfig = processEngineConfig.getDmnEngineConfiguration();
        dmnEngineConfig.customPostDecisionTableEvaluationListeners(Collections.singletonList(new DmnDecisionTableEvaluationListener(){

            @Override
            public void notify(DmnDecisionTableEvaluationEvent event) {
                String dmnID = event.getDecisionTable().getKey();
                Map<String, TypedValue> dmnInput = event.getInputs().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(DmnEvaluatedInput::getName, DmnEvaluatedInput::getValue));
                List<DmnEvaluatedDecisionRule> matchingRuleList = new ArrayList<>();
                matchingRuleList = event.getMatchingRules();
                log.info("DMN ID = {}", dmnID);
                log.info("DMN Input = {}", dmnInput);

                if(null != matchingRuleList) {
                    log.info("DMN Matched Rules = {}", matchingRuleList.size());
                    if(!matchingRuleList.isEmpty()) {
                        for(DmnEvaluatedDecisionRule rule : matchingRuleList) {
                            log.info("DMN Matching Rule ID = {}", rule.getId());
                            log.info("DMN Output = {}", rule.getOutputEntries());
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        log.info("DMN Output = No matching rule found");
                    }
                }
                log.info("************************************************************************************************");
            }
        }));
        dmnEngineConfig.buildEngine();
        processEngineConfig.setDmnEngineConfiguration(dmnEngineConfig);
    }
}
```

There is another way to get the matching rule details - by implementing `ProcessEnginePlugin` and `overriding postProcessEngineBuild()` and `preInit()` methods instead of extending `AbstractCamundaConfiguration` and `overriding postInit()` method as above.